# Is there an updated google code playground that supports maps v3?

Tags: google-maps

Google has a cool tool to allow you to play with different aspects of their API available at http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/

This currently only has examples for v2 of the maps api.

Does anyone know if there's an updated version that supports v3?